# Is an Enderman classified as a monster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to go to bed, but it's not letting me. I have a showcase in my house that is upstairs, and that showcase has a trapped Enderman in it.  Everything else in my showcase is an animal. Could it be that the Enderman that is causing my bed to tell me I can't sleep?

Comment: What is a showcase?  I assume it's not the showcase mod.

Comment: @John He just means a collection of animals for display.

Comment: @SadlyNot mobs would despawn once he moves away correct?

Answer (score 11):

According to the MC wiki, a *hostile* mob prevents you sleeping. An enderman is considered a *neutral* mob unless provoked, so it *should not* prevent you sleeping.

> In recent and current versions of Minecraft, nightmares are gone, but you cannot sleep if a hostile mob is within 8 blocks of the bed horizontally (along each axis) and 5 blocks vertically.

also

> An Enderman (plural Endermen) is a three-block-high, humanoid, neutral mob that will turn hostile when provoked.

To answer your question, an enderman is not considered a monster.
**Regardless of this** I tested this in the latest version of Minecraft and it **did** prevent me sleeping. So although it's classified wrong, it still prevents you from sleeping.

Comment: +1 for Science! Yeah, the wiki is just wrong. By the code an Enderman is a hostile mob that just can't see the player until provoked.

Comment: Really now? I'll have to take a look at the code sometime, I like playing around with those things.

Comment: [This](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Installation/Source) is a straightforward way to get the decompiled code up and working. It's a tangle, but quite interesting to browse through!

Answer (score 0):

Yup. The enderman is classified as hostile mob to me, because it attacks if you stare at it. Do that with a spider. Same thing happens... except quicker. You should probably put the showcase somewhere else.

Comment: But before it's stared at, it is classified as neutral. It's only once it's provoked that it becomes hostile.

Comment: The code is the problem. It's set as hostile no matter what.